# Flutter Move to next line of code after getting answers from api

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function which calls 4 api.

```
  getDefects();
  getInstruction();
  getToDone();
  getToInvoice();
```

and after that it would update UI of my app.

```
  status.success();
  update(['all']);
```

i want this function to call all 4 api together and not wait for their answers but when the answer for all 4 api came back it moves to next part of code which updates UI

```
 getData() async {
 status.loading();

try {
  getDefects();
  getInstruction();
  getToDone();
  getToInvoice();
  
  status.success();
  update(['all']);

  } catch (e) {
  status.error(e.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: you want to go next page when all API calls complete

Comment: You can use Future.wait for this

Comment: @RohitSuthar i implemeted it like this
Future.wait([
        getDefects(),
        getInstruction(),
        getToDone(),
        getToInvoice(),
      ]);
the thing is that it allowed them to be called but wont wait for them to finish compeletly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateState(int count) {
    if (count == 4) {
        status.success();
        update(['all']);
    }
}

getData() async {
    status.loading();
    int count = 0;

    try {
        getDefects().then(value => updateState(count++);
        getInstruction().then(value => updateState(count++);
        getToDone().then(value => updateState(count++);
        getToInvoice().then(value => updateState(count++);
    } catch (e) {
        status.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a wise answer and it works.